# Uploading VS project to Devops get repository

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a repository, called Sandbox for Lee with a folder Maint/FunctionApps/FluidSampleFunciton. I have never had to load a project to a GIT Repository before and am having no luck. I have found a number of articles. one saying to create a clone of the repository on my machine. so I did that. I saved my project to that local repository in the FluidSampleFunction folder. I then tried a push, pull push. still nothing. It can be that hard to upload a project to a Git Repository.

Comment: Can you post the commands you are running and their outputs (**as text**) in the question?

Comment: I am doing every thing from VS 2022, not using command lines

Comment: Then can you give any more detail?

Comment: In your description of what you did, you never mentioned that you ever committed anything. Did you make any commits?

Comment: ok I am able to get it upload to my GET Repository. thanks to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222880/push-an-existing-project-into-a-new-azure-devops-repository-in-visual-studio-202  However when I am pulling down my sandbox get it is the MAIN branch How can I pull down my develop branch instead. or should I say Clone the develop branch

Comment: After you clone, you can checkout any branch you wish, so `git checkout develop` or `git switch develop`. ("switch" is the newer version of the "checkout" command when used to switch branches.)